# submit for with either php or jquery using get but no ajax functionality

Tags: php

im trying to figure out how i can do this.

i have a list of names being pulled from the database and when i click on a name i want another page to load with that names details.

I've done this before using ajax in an ajax driven contact book i made, but now i need to be able to take that persons name attach it to the $_GET and submit the form so another page loads with the persons name, just by having that persons name I can query my database.

Thats easy, but the trick here is that i have like 10 names being pulled from the database inside of a while loop.

so now I have ten tables with short details of the person along with their name. I want to have a click here for more details option. Thats whats confusing me, I don't want to use javascript just yet if at all possible. But without jquery I don't know how to grab the ID of the name. which is pointing towards the ajax route which i don't want to go into at this time.

any help would really be appreciated.

here is my while loop code with my attempt:

```
            <? while($project = mysql_fetch_assoc($pquery)){ ?>
             <form action="projectview.php" method="GET" id="viewproject">
                    <table border="0" align="right" style="border-bottom: 1px dashed #BDBDBD;" width="100%">
                    <tr><td colspan="2"><span><input type="submit" name="view" id="<?=$project['idProjects'];?>"><?=$project['project_name'];?><input type="hidden" name="<?=$project['idProjects'];?>"></span></td></tr>
                    <tr><td align="right" colspan="2"><span>post-production</span></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Time:</td><td><?=daysDifference($project['end_date']);?> remaining</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Budget:&nbsp;</td><td><?=$project['actual_budget'];?></td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="2"><?=$project['end_date'];?></td></tr>
                    </table>
              </form>  
                <br />
                <div style="padding: 3px;">&nbsp;</div>
             <? } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you're asking, but from what I can gather you want a list of names and each name has a "more info" link to a page that uses GET for parameters. For that you don't need to use forms, you can go with normal links and append the GET data to the link.

```
<?php while($project = mysql_fetch_assoc($pquery)){ ?>
    <?php echo $project[ 'project_name' ]; ?>
    <a href="projectview.php?projectId=<?php echo $project[ 'idProjects' ]; ?>">
        click here for more info
    </a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I agree, when you're not asking a user for any data, a simple link will be better.

Comment: hmmm I get it, on my other page how do I get the get parameter so I can use it in a variable?

Comment: The data is transferred just like in a form, for example $projectId = $_GET[ 'projectId' ]

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear for me what is your problem. If you need to distinguish which form has been sent, you already have your hidden input. Just set a fixed name and change the value.

```
<input type="hidden" name="project" value="<?=$project['idProjects'];?>
```